Programmatic launch of a "Customize Channels" window in Android
Please, tell me, who knows. How to programmatically open the channel editing menu in Android TV?
enter image description here
I tried:
public void showCustomizeChannelsMenu() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.google.android.tvlauncher", "com.google.android.tvlauncher.settings.AppChannelPermissionActivity"));

        if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Не удалось открыть настройки каналов", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }


There is no requirement for that menu to exist on any given Android TV device. For those that offer it, there is no requirement for it to be available to third-party apps for display.

@CommonsWare, thanks!

Ok. I found out that the most I can do is bring up the "Home Screen" menu that includes menu "Customize Channels":
public void showCustomizeChannelsSidePanel() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.google.android.tvlauncher", "com.google.android.tvlauncher.settings.HomeScreenSettingsActivity"));

        if (intent.resolveActivity(activity.getPackageManager()) != null) {
            activity.startActivity(intent);
            Logger.debugCapture( "method showCustomizeChannelsMenu", Logger.ErrorLevel.INFO );
        } else {
            Logger.debugCapture( "method showCustomizeChannelsMenu is unavailable", Logger.ErrorLevel.INFO );
        }
    }

